# How can I create a Delphi child window that has a main menu?

Tags: delphi, menu, childwindow

I am working with a Delphi form that contains a TMainMenu. In a particular situation I want to show this form parented and client-aligned inside another form. This works fine but the main menu of the parented form does not appear. I see a comment in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968598/problem-while-using-two-forms) that states "A child window cannot have a menu". Is there anything that I can do to override this behaviour and make a TMainMenu appear?

An aside: I've only just noticed this because where I have used this principle before, I've been using the Developer Express menu component and this is quite happy to show in a child form.

Later edit:
Using the code from TLama below, this works (but the child menu is not themed, I,e very plain):
This works:

```
procedure TForm65.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Winapi.Windows.SetParent(ChildForm.Handle, Handle); // <<<<<<<<
  ChildForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  ChildForm.Align := alClient;
  ChildForm.Show;
end;
```

This code DOES NOT work. Why?

```
procedure TForm65.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ChildForm.Parent := Self; // <<<<<<<<<
  ChildForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  ChildForm.Align := alClient;
  ChildForm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Showing a form in a form is a bit odd (if no MDI interface). What if you replace the form with a Frame?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I've tried to use a code [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/kC8mkff7), but the main menu placed on the `ChildForm` remains and works just fine (Delphi 2009).

Comment: @whosrdaddy: But it's cool! Sometimes I let my standard controls (e.g. buttons) have window frames just for the fun of it.

Comment: @TLama: Your code does work but the menu is very plain (missing theme?). I would like to know why my Parent assignment fails but yours (nearly) works.

Comment: @Brian Calling SetParent doesn't make the window become a child window. This is explained in the documentation for SetParent. My answer is accurate. After all, the documentation on MSDN could not be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#child) makes this perfectly clear:

> A child window has a client area but no other features, unless they are explicitly requested. An application can request a title bar, a window menu, minimize and maximize buttons, a border, and scroll bars for a child window, but a child window cannot have a menu.

This refers to the menu as drawn by Windows itself. If your component custom draws a menu bar, then of course it can have a menu, even if it is a child window.

---

Your call to `SetParent` does not make your window into a child window. This is explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541.aspx):

> For compatibility reasons, SetParent does not modify the WS_CHILD or WS_POPUP window styles of the window whose parent is being changed. Therefore, if hWndNewParent is NULL, you should also clear the WS_CHILD bit and set the WS_ POPUP style after calling SetParent. Conversely, if hWndNewParent is not NULL and the window was previously a child of the desktop, you should clear the WS_POPUP style and set the WS_CHILD style before calling SetParent.

Comment: I believe what OP silently wants MDI child window, rather the general child window. It does not make much difference in the menu part, but still...

Comment: @david ok I now understand that SetParent is what is wanted and we see that it works. Could you go further now to explain why SetParent behaves differently from ChildForm.Parent := Self?

Comment: I already did. It's in the MSDN extract in my answer. You are not setting the WS_CHILD style when you call SetParent. So your window is not a child window. It's still a popup window, WS_POPUP.